# Syntax error binding to a static resource in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I am having a problem with accessing Application Resources from a UserControl in my Silverlight application.  Here is my UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.MainControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:basics="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls" >
    <basics:TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
        <basics:TabItem Name="tabHome" Header="Home"></basics:TabItem>
        <basics:TabItem Name="tabPatients" Header="{StaticResource My_Patients}"></basics:TabItem>
        <basics:TabItem Name="tabOrganization" Header="My Organization"></basics:TabItem>
    </basics:TabControl>
</UserControl>
```

I am getting an error on the line where I set the Header property of the tabPatients tab to the static resource My_Patients.

Here is my Application file:

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
             x:Class="MyApp.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <System:String x:Key="My_Patients">All My Patients</System:String>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with it, works fine on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall, this is a bug that's been around for some time--you can specify a string `StaticResource` for a string property, but not for a content control's content (i.e. the `TabItem`'s `Header`).

I may be wrong, but I think the following workaround may help:

```
Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource My_Patients}}"
```

At any rate, if your goal is to make your application localizable, I'd recommend reading [Tim Heuer's blog post on the subject](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/08/26/silverlight-string-localization.aspx).

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, although come to think of it I do have SL4 installed.

Comment: The problem was definitely still around in SL3--I haven't tried it in 4 yet.